# GTK: Mouse events grab on GTK Socket

Tags: events, gtk, gtk3, x11

I have encountered a problem with Gtk.Socket and mouse event. I don't receive any Mouse event signals in Gtk.Socket.

When I create Gtk.Socket and embed some app supporting XEMBED protocol into it(for example rxvt-unicode), i want to be able to hook mouse events on the socket(for focus change, popup menu, etc). But the Gtk.Socket itself doesnt receive any Mouse Event.

I'm new to GTK(actually also in X11) world. So i'm not sure how events are distributed to windows. I'm almost pretty sure, that this embedded window eat all mouse events and doesnt send them to their parent(in my case Gtk.Socket). Is it possible to hack it somehow?

This is short example:
(i removed everything i tried to get button-press-event), to keep it short).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import GdkX11, Gtk, Gdk
from subprocess import Popen

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, size_x, size_y):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
        self.resize(size_x, size_y)
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

        self.default_structure()

    def default_structure(self):
        child1 = TerminalWindow()
        child2 = TerminalWindow()

        layout = Gtk.HBox()
        layout.pack_start(child1, True, True, 0)
        layout.pack_start(child2, True, True, 0)
        self.add(layout)

class TerminalWindow(Gtk.Socket):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

        self.connect('realize', self.on_realize)
        self.connect('unrealize', Gtk.main_quit)

    def on_realize(self, *args):
        self.inner_process = Popen(['urxvt', '-embed', str(self.get_id()), '-pe', '-tabbed'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = MainWindow(800, 300)
    win.show_all()

    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: In X11, windows don't normally send events to other windows, or pass them to parent windows. Instead, a program registers interest in events that happen to a window. Any program can watch any window. It is not clear why you want that though. rxvt can have its own popup window, and if you add another one, it will be somewhat messy.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately you cannot probably register mouse events, that happen to another window. :-( Why i want to do this? First - if i have 2 embedded urxvt, i want to change focus on them on click. Second urxvt is missing something like terminator - splitting, grouping, etc... thats what i want to do. Thats why popup(it can be with some key modifier, problem is i cannot hook mouse event at all)

Comment: Why, you can, no problem with that, but better create an *InputOnly* window over your socket and take input from it.

Comment: Well, i can, but it doesn't work. Problem is probably in here: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSelectInput.html  MouseButtonPress can be listened on one client. So if i get you right you suggest to make some transparent overlay over GtkSocket? BUt wouldnt it hinder the urxvt window that creates itself there too? Ill try it...

Comment: Hm. I think you will need to raise the inputonly window when your embedded window loses focus, and lower it on click.

Comment: Hmm, thats not that nice.. :/